# Partial execution of a synchronization block in java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-synchronization

I was just curious is it possible that a thread T1 say executes a synchronization block partially and then releases the lock on the object and another thread T2 executes the same block? Something like this:

```
line1: synchronized(this){
line2:  if(INSTANCE == null)
line3:   INSTANCE = new Object(); //say a variable is initialized
line4:  return INSTANCE;
line5: }
```

Is it possible that thread T1 acquires a lock on current object (`this`) and executes line1 and line2. Then thread T1 is preempted by thread T2, T1 releases lock and T2 acquires lock on `this` and executes the same block (all the lines1 to 5). Then thread T1 again takes the lock and continues executing from line3?

Basically, T1 will see `INSTANCE` as null and so will T2 and each will create a new Object.

If this is not possible can someone explain why not?

Addendum:

Thanks everyone for your answer. My question was a bit misleading. What I am exactly asking, is it possible that once a thread is executing a synchronized block it can release the lock before the entire block is executed (not by explicitly calling `wait()` but something which is process, CPU dependent)? Is there a contract in JLS or a JVM guarantee that once a thread starts executing a synchronized block the lock on the object is not released until the end of the block? My understanding is synchronization guarantees no 2 threads can simultaneously execute the block (or other synchronized method/block) but the lock is hold until the end of the block is reached? It's kind of obvious but is it specified in the JLS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thread preemption doesn't cause the preempted thread to release its locks. If it did, locks would be worthless. The whole point of a `synchronized` block is that it will disallow other threads from synchronizing on the same object until the thread releases the lock (by leaving the `synchronized` block).

Answer (score 1):

Even if a thread is preempted, it won't release a lock.  The lock is still held.  If another thread comes along, it will block (stop running) until the lock is released, even if the original thread gets preempted several times before it releases the lock.  Basically almost any kind of lock has some storage in the heap that gets written to indicate there's a lock.  It's permanent until the thread or the system writes a different value to indicate the lock is free.

It is of course possible to write code that allows access to an instance or field without ever taking the lock, but that's a coding error.  It's also possible for the original thread to exit the block early (say it throws an exception) -- this releases the lock, and other threads can continue as normal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's not possible for a second thread to enter the `synchronize` block before the first one has executed the entire block. On obtaining the lock on the object, all other threads attempting to enter the synchronized code will be blocked.

See more information here: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/synchronized.html

Comment: True except in the special case where the first thread calls `wait()` on the synchronized object.

Answer (score -1):

Basically you can use [Locks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html) objects. Lock objects can allow you to sequentially apply and release locks on multiple locks line by line.

A very good tutorial on how to implement it [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/locks.html)

Check out below code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;




public class test2{

    private static Object instance = null;
    private static test2 t = new test2();
    private static Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        a.setName("Thread-A");
        b.setName("Thread-B");
        a.start();
        b.start();
    }

    public Object getObj(){
        try {
            lock.lock();
            System.out.println("Begin Current thread:  "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
            if(instance == null){
                if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Thread-A")){
                    lock.unlock();
                    while(instance==null){
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +"  :  instance is null");
                    }
                    while(true){
                        if(!lock.tryLock()){
                           System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " waiting for re lock");
                        }else{
                           lock.lock();
                           break;
                       }
                    }
                }
                instance =new Object();
                System.out.println("End Current thread:  "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
                if (((ReentrantLock) lock).isHeldByCurrentThread()) {
                    lock.unlock();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return instance;
    }


    public static class A extends Thread{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true){
                if(t.getObj() != null){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public  static class B extends Thread{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true){
                if(t.getObj() != null){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
Begin Current thread:  Thread-A
Thread-A  :  instance is null
Begin Current thread:  Thread-B
Thread-A  :  instance is null
End Current thread:  Thread-B
Thread-A waiting for re lock
End Current thread:  Thread-A
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My question was a bit misleading. What I am exactly asking, is it possible that once a thread is executing a synchronized block it can release the lock before the entire block is executed?

Comment: Hi..Your answer is not related to the question and will confuse others who are looking for answer. I am not looking for HOW TO IMPLEMENT lock or re-entrant lock; more in the lines IS IT POSSIBLE FOR A THREAD TO RELEASE A LOCK BEFORE COMPLETING THE SYNC BLOCK. Thanks

Comment: @SubhomoySikdar the wordings of the question was modified from the version i answered it.  You arent proving a point here by typing in capslock and that too after four years since it was answered?

Comment: And people usually dont go beyond the accepted answer for you to be worried about people being mislead. There is a comment section to comment on that.

Comment: Hello..I did not modify the wordings of my question...I just explained it more in the addendum...I am really not sure what your ask is? There is no correlation between your answer and the question...as for 4 years..you commented recently on an old thread asking me to explain the downvote

Comment: The downvote happened on may 8th and you yourself said in your very first comment that your question was misleading. People put effort to answer your queries, its easy to just say oh i added addendum later (modified a bit or added clarity when someone asked you to) and then later people just come and downvote .. Anyway.. water under the bridge..

Comment: ok..hate to break it to you..i did not downvote your answer..when you said may 8..i checked..it was someone else